# Can I write an activerecord scope which wraps the result in a block at query time?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord, database-replication

Our rails app has a primary and a replica DB.  We already have a method defined which takes a block, and while inside the block, queries will be made against the replica, like so:

```rb
on_replica do
  @my_things = MyModel.where(my_attr: "my value").to_a
end
```

This works well in most cases, but if you don't actually perform the query in the block, it doesn't work:

```rb
on_replica do
  @my_things = MyModel.where(my_attr: "my value")
end

# this will run its query against the primary DB
@my_things.to_a
```

I'd really like to be able to define a scope (or scope-like thing) so that any query happening past that point in the method chain happens against the replica:

```rb
@my_things = MyModel.where(my_attr: "my value").eventually_on_replica

# this runs its query against the replica DB:
@my_things.to_a
```

Is it possible to define an `eventually_on_replica` method that would work this way, using the existing `on_replica` method?  Bonus points if `MyModel.eventually_on_replica.where(my_attr: "my value")` works too.

Comment: How should this behave? `on_replica { query = MyModel.where(....) }; on_primary { query = query.where(....) }; query.to_a` -- This is now a contradictory set of requirements :)

Comment: It might help if you showed how `on_replica` is currently defined. AFAIK, such a method would basically be a wrapper around `ActiveRecord::Base.connected_to`, but I don't think it's logical/possible for it to work in the way you describe.

Comment: However, I also don't think it's necessary/desirable!... Why would you want/need to specify the connection, **outside of the context** where the connection is actually being established?? If a query needs to be run on the replica DB, then why can't that be specified at the point of querying?

Comment: @TomLord We don't have an `on_primary` method, and don't have a use case for one.

Perhaps I've made a mistake using the name `on_replica` twice here.  The first one I mention _already exists_; I don't need help writing it.  Where I need help is in writing the second one which works like a scope.

I'll update the question.

Comment: @TomLord you ask "why can't that be specified at the point of querying" - because the specification happens in a controller, and the querying happens in a view.  We can't just call `to_a`, as we want to use `will_paginate` with this, if possible.

Answer (score 2):

my idea is to wrap your `on_replica` into a `relation` then we can append it at the end of query chains.

i don't know whether your `on_replica` will work on this proposal or not, i just demo with [ActiveRecord::Base.connected_to](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_multiple_databases.html#horizontal-sharding)

```rb
# lib/active_record/base.rb
module ActiveRecord
  module Querying
    delegate :eventually_on_replica, to: :all
  end

  class Relation
    def eventually_on_replica(database: nil, role: nil, shard: nil, prevent_writes: false)
      ActiveRecord::Base.connected_to(
        database: database,
        role: role,
        shard: shard,
        prevent_writes: prevent_writes
      ) do
        self.load
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Demo

```rb
# config/application.rb
config.active_record.reading_role = :dev
config.active_record.reading_role = :test

# models/application_record.rb
class ApplicationRecord < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.abstract_class = true

  connects_to database: { dev: :development, test: :test }
end

# database development
result = Requirement.where(id: [1,2,3]).eventually_on_replica(role: :dev)
result.to_a # have data

# database test
result = Requirement.where(id: [1,2,3]).eventually_on_replica(role: :test)
result.to_a # [] no data
```

So you can try replace `ActiveRecord::Base.connected_to` by your `on_relica`.

In case of `Model.eventually_on_replica.where`, i need to set a flag to mark that is running `on replica` then try to cache all query chains in order to execute later (on `connected_to` block) and it turns out a very complex case and maybe effect other queries in normal case so i don't go further.

Answer (score 0):

For the `eventually_on_replica` method at the end of the chain, I have a simple method.

In your `application_record.rb` file (if you have it, otherwise you may need to patch `ActiveRecord::Base`

```rb
# app/models/application_record.rb
class ApplicationRecord < ActiveRecord::Base

  def self.eventually_on_replica
    on_replica do
      self.all
    end
  end

end
```

However, as soon as you call `eventually_on_replica`, it will run the DB query and load the results. It doesn't support lazy loading but after all, you only need to call `eventually_on_replica` when you really need the results so maybe this will work for your use case.